# Make points "look" under surface in R using lattice and wireframe

Tags: r, 3d, points, lattice, wireframe

I've been working on a rather complicated chart in R.  I have a wireframe with a surface and points distributed in X,Y,Z space all over (e.g. under the surface and over it).

The problem is that the points that plot don't "look" like they are underneath the surface.

I am trying to figure out how best to visualize this chart to make the points look under the surface.  Some sample code for the wireframe & cloud come from here:  [R-List Posting](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/05/11/16135.html)

The code in an example:

```
library(lattice)
surf <-
expand.grid(x = seq(-pi, pi, length = 50),
            y = seq(-pi, pi, length = 50))

surf$z <-
with(surf, {
    d <- 3 * sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
    exp(-0.02 * d^2) * sin(d)
})

g <- surf

pts <-   data.frame(x =rbind(2,2,2), y=rbind(-2,-2,-2), z=rbind(.5,0,-.5))

wireframe(z ~ x * y, g, aspect = c(1, .5),
      drape=TRUE,
      scales = list(arrows = FALSE),
      pts = pts,
      panel.3d.wireframe =
      function(x, y, z,
               xlim, ylim, zlim,
               xlim.scaled, ylim.scaled, zlim.scaled,
               pts,
               ...) {
          panel.3dwire(x = x, y = y, z = z,
                       xlim = xlim,
                       ylim = ylim,
                       zlim = zlim,
                       xlim.scaled = xlim.scaled,
                       ylim.scaled = ylim.scaled,
                       zlim.scaled = zlim.scaled,
                       ...)
          xx <-
              xlim.scaled[1] + diff(xlim.scaled) *
                  (pts$x - xlim[1]) / diff(xlim)
          yy <-
              ylim.scaled[1] + diff(ylim.scaled) *
                  (pts$y - ylim[1]) / diff(ylim)
          zz <-
              zlim.scaled[1] + diff(zlim.scaled) *
                  (pts$z - zlim[1]) / diff(zlim)
          panel.3dscatter(x = xx,
                          y = yy,
                          z = zz,
                          xlim = xlim,
                          ylim = ylim,
                          zlim = zlim,
                          xlim.scaled = xlim.scaled,
                          ylim.scaled = ylim.scaled,
                          zlim.scaled = zlim.scaled,
                          ...)
      })
```

[image: Screen Capture]

Looking at my example, the points in pts are in actually in vertical line where X,Y =(2,-2) and the z goes from .5 to -.5.

However, to my eye the third point doesn't look like it is under the surface, to it looks like it is at coordinates(2,-3,0).

Is this just my eye mis-interpreting this ?

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to make my points look more "3D" ? Perhaps muting the color of the point to make it look "under the surface" by using some sort of transparency on the surface ?

I tried making the colors of the points different (red for over the surface, blue for under the surface) but that does not really help the graph much.

Comment: this would be much more straightforward using the rgl package, which has full support for transparency, lighting, and construction of a scene where objects are known to be 'in front of' or 'behind' particular surfaces

Comment: How would I convert my code above to use rgl ?  I've not used it before ..

Comment: Hi Ben, I am totally confused by rgl.  Frankly I am not sure where to start.  Could you give me some pointers on moving to rgl ?  Thanks !

Comment: I dont know if its viable, but how about changing the size depending on the distance to some point that represents the viewer.

Comment: If you don't want to play w/ `rgl` then either trying Marco's idea about perspective or consider drawing the points "under" with a lighter value or a transparency.  R supports hex transparency codes via `color=#xxyyzzaa`, where the first three hex pairs are RGB and the last is the transparency (00= invisible, ff= full color).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might get you started:

```
library(emdbook)
sfun <- function(x,y) {
  d <- 3 * sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
  exp(-0.02 * d^2) * sin(d)
}

cc <- curve3d(sfun(x,y),xlim=c(-pi,pi),ylim=c(-pi,pi),n=c(50,50),
        sys3d="rgl")

colvec <- colorRampPalette(c("pink","white","lightblue"))(100)
with(cc,persp3d(x,y,z,col=colvec[cut(z,100)],alpha=0.5))
pts <-   data.frame(x=c(2,2,2), y=c(-2,-2,-2), z=c(.5,0,-.5))
with(pts,spheres3d(x,y,z,col="blue",radius=0.1))
rgl.snapshot("rgltmp1.png")
```

[image]